# Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an error like this. is anyone know how to fix it.

***Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure `"LibraryMonitoringSystem.Properties.Resources.resources"` was correctly embedded or linked into assembly `"LibraryMonitoringSystem"` at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.***

I also tried to read this links

[Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690713/could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate-for-the-specified-culture-or-the-neutra)

[Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058441/could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate-for-the-specified-culture-or-the-neutra)

[Could not find any resources for the specified culture or the neutral culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153997/could-not-find-any-resources-for-the-specified-culture-or-the-neutral-culture)

[.NET 4.0 to 3.0 could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263491/net-4-0-to-3-0-could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate-for-the-specified-cultu)

[Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture (C# WinForm Images in Resource File)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923953/could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate-for-the-specified-culture-c-winform-i)

but none of them solve my problem..

Comment: Do you have any code to show?

Comment: Do you have Resource File(.resx) in your application ?If so i guess you got to Embed it

Comment: Yes i have my resource file and in the properties `Build Action` i put `Embedded Resources` but still the error shows

Comment: @MarcusWigert : I think its not in the code well i don't know but which code you need?